# Convert timestamp to date/time?

Tags: sql, ms-access, timestamp, ms-access-2010

I have a number field with data like:

```
875612015
644936666
644936071
644939568
673358599
665166803
```

These should be date/times, how can I convert these to readable date/times in SQL (select statement)?

To reverse engineer some data points:

```
                 |
11/10/10   1219 = 968674746
11/12/10   1033 = 968841218
11/12/10   1302 = 968850160
11/12/10   1332 = 968851974
11/16/10   1212 = 969192756
11/16/10   1526 = 969204361
07/19/12   1036 = 1021977398
```

These time values are likely stored in something related to [MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS)

Comment: What do the numbers represent?  Number of seconds?  milliseconds?

Comment: @PaulStock Honestly, I'm not sure. This is being pulled from a 3rd party data source w/ no documentation. All I know is this represents a date/time the record was created at. It's likely related to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS

Comment: @PaulStock Looks like Unix to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DateAdd ( "s", DATENUMBERFIELD, #01/01/1970# )
FROM SourceDatabase
```

**UPDATE:**

OK, based on your examples, looks like the base date is 03/01/1980, not 1/1/1970 so try this:

```
SELECT DateAdd ( "s", DATENUMBERFIELD, #03/01/1980# )
FROM SourceDatabase
```

Comment: A date/time comes out, but it might be ~10 years off. I provided some reverse engineering of the times in the question.

Comment: @JBurace from your examples, it looks like the base date is 3/1/80, so I've updated my code